# glPointSize isn't working

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glPointSize(20.0);
glBegin(GL_POINT); 
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
} 
glEnd();
glFlush();
```

This is my source code.
glPointSize function isn't working.

does anyone know about this problem?

Comment: glLineWIdth() does not work too.

Comment: I tested it on my pc and I did no get any point. Do you see anything or do you have a black screen? Errors in OpenGL-render-code often causes black screens. I have used `glGetError()` to request the error code. I got `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. Since `glBegin` is the only function in your code which takes an GLenum, I checked the [documentation of the funktion](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml). You have to use `GL_POINTS` insted of `GL_POINT`. After I changed it, anythink worked.

Comment: @JojOatXGME: you are perfectly right about the cause of the problem, but the `glBegin` is not the only function taking `GLenum` in this code snippet... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GL_POINTS` instead of `GL_POINT`.

Therefore, the code should change to:

```
*
glBegin(GL_POINTS); 
*
```

Answer (score -2):

use the following:

```
glEnable(0x8642);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
```

and then increase the size of the vertex using either one of these:

```
glPointSize(10.0f); //in the application
// OR
gl_PointSize(10.0f); //in your vertex shader
```

Comment: What is 0x8642?